# How to make google flags ignore unknown command line flags?

Tags: c++, gflags

I'm using google flags for command line parsing. It's a wonderful tool, but somehow I need it to ignore unknown flags instead of print a line of

```
ERROR: unknown command line flag ...
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a [`flagfile`](http://gflags.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/gflags.html#special) , unrecognised flags are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

**"--someflag1=1 --someflags2=4 --undefok=someflag1,someflag2"** will cause no error if someflag1 or someflag2 is not defined.  However, if they are defined then they would get values define in commandline.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in Google Flags' source code for [CommandLineFlagParser](http://code.google.com/p/gflags/source/browse/trunk/src/gflags.cc?r=81#898), it does its parsing in 2 stages: stage 1 is parsing anything that looks like a flag, and if it doesn't know what to do with it, it is stored for error report afterward. There is no option to change that behaviour.